# Arithmetic using picklists

Tags: trigger

I am getting error : Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments (Line No 13)

```
trigger CheckBoxNew on Opportunity (before insert, before update)

{
    for(Opportunity opp:trigger.new)
    {
        if (opp.TERADATA_CHECK_BOX__c == true){
            Product2 pr = new Product2();
            Product_Pricing__c ppr = new Product_Pricing__c();
            //product pro = new product();
            opp.TERADATA_MARGIN_AMOUNT__c = ppr.Unit_Actual_Price__c *pr.TERADATA_MARGIN__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the data type of Unit_Actual_Price__c, TERADATA_MARGIN__c, TERADATA_MARGIN_AMOUNT__c

Comment: @SanTosh - Unit Actual - Currency
TERADATA_MARGIN - Currency 
TERADATA_MARGIN_AMOUNT__c - Picklist

Comment: You are multiplying margin with actual price. Both should be numerical i.e. number, percentage

Comment: you should convert TERADATA_MARGIN_AMOUNT__c to integer prior to using it for calculations. So, the solution would be to parse as follows:
`Decimal.valueOf(pr.TERADATA_MARGIN__c)`

Comment: @SanTosh That converts it to `Decimal`, not `Integer`.

Comment: @SanTosh - not working..